Android Bundling failed



header 1
header 2




cell 1
cell 2


cell 3
cell 4






header 1
header 2




cell 1
cell 2


cell 3
cell 4




I have problem when wrap app.js with <ClerkProvider> and after reaload the project i had this error message :

Android Bundling failed 589ms C:\My Work\React Native\First\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js (1 module)
Unable to resolve "@clerk/shared" from "node_modules\@clerk\clerk-react\dist\index.js
Here's the app.js :
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Login from './Apps/Screens/LoginScreen/Login';
import { ClerkProvider,SignedIn, SignedOut  } from "@clerk/clerk-expo";


export default function App() {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider publishableKey={'pk_test_ZGFzaGluZy1maXNoLTc0LmNsZXJrLmFjY291bnRzLmRldiQ'}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <SignedIn>
              <Text>You are Signed in</Text>
          </SignedIn>
          <SignedOut>
              <Login/>
          </SignedOut>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}

And here's the package.json :
{
  "name": "first",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --tunnel",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@clerk/clerk-expo": "^1.1.4",
    "expo": "~51.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.74.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

Android Bundling failed 589ms C:\My Work\React Native\First\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js (1 module)
Unable to resolve "@clerk/shared" from "node_modules\@clerk\clerk-react\dist\index.js"

I fixed this problem with updated the version of react because it was a conflict between react native and react versions, So just i run updated the react version with this cmd :
npm install --save react@^18.3.1

